# OWL-Reasoner for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, owl, reasoner

I´m looking for an owl-reasoner for nodejs. Are there any sutible packages out there?
I have searched the npm, but didn´t found anything good.

best regards

Comment: OWL 2 RL (partially): https://github.com/ucbl/HyLAR-Reasoner

Comment: Yes, I've already tried this, but the docs are not that detailed ...